# Need to measure coordinates value from absolute axis system

Tags: vba, catia

Please help me to solve this problem.

I want to measure the Hole COG. I wrote the code it was working fine but the problem the COG value was taken from the local axis.
I want it to always extract COG relative to the absolute axis system. By default, it picks the local axis

please find the code below here

```
Sub main()

Dim oPartDoc As document
Set oPartDoc = CATIA.ActiveDocument

Dim selection2 As Selection
Set selection2 = oPartDoc.Selection


selection2.Search ("Type=Hole,all")

For i = 1 To selection2.Count

Dim ocircle As Variant

Set ocircle = selection2.Item(i).Value


        Set TheSPAWorkbench = CATIA.ActiveDocument.GetWorkbench("SPAWorkbench")
        Set TheMeasurable = TheSPAWorkbench.GetMeasurable(ocircle)
    
        Dim Coordinates(2)
        TheMeasurable.GetCOG Coordinates
        x1 = Coordinates(0)
        y1 = Coordinates(1)
        z1 = Coordinates(2)

        
        MsgBox "Center of gravity : X = " & _
            CStr(Coordinates(0)) & ", Y = " + CStr(Coordinates(1)) & ", Z = " + CStr(Coordinates(2))

Next

selection2.Clear
End Sub
```

Comment: Matrix transformation calculation.

Comment: Thankyou for your comment

 Sorry, Can you tell something brief so that I can understand better

Comment: You have to calculate your measured coordinates into the other axis system using a coordinate transformation.

Comment: If i can share an external link, i should recomand you this link below. You will have all functions you need to transform coords or points into an other axis system.     https://www.eng-tips.com/faqs.cfm?fid=1824

Answer (score 2):

There are new methods starting with R28 which allow you to easily do measurements in assembly context.
There is no more need to perform transformations or to play games with strings to make product references.

SPAWorkbench.GetMeasurableInContext(partReference,instanceProduct) is all that you need to do a COG.

Here is an example

```
Dim oRoot As Product
Set oRoot = CATIA.ActiveDocument.Product

Dim oPartProd As Product
Set oPartProd = oRoot.Products.Item("Part2.1") 'this is a specific instance product

Dim oPart As Part
Set oPart = oPartProd.ReferenceProduct.Parent.Part 'get the part from the instance product

Dim oBodyRef As Reference
Set oBodyRef = oPart.CreateReferenceFromObject(oPart.Bodies.Item(1)) 'part reference to the PartBody

Dim oSPA As SPAWorkbench
Set oSPA = CATIA.ActiveDocument.GetWorkbench("SPAWorkbench") 'get the SPA workbench from the root assembly

Dim oRefMeasurable As Measurable
Set oRefMeasurable = oSPA.GetMeasurableInContext(oBodyRef, oPartProd) 'measurable in assembly context *NEW in R29*

Dim cog(2)
Dim vMeas As Variant
Set vMeas = oRefMeasurable
Call vMeas.GetCOG(cog)

Debug.Print "PRODUCT COG = " & cog(0) & " " & cog(1) & " " & cog(2)
```

Comment: Thankyou so much it works well